# "After being" vs "After one has been"

Tags: tenses, pronouns, third-person

Sentence:

> "What is one to do, **after being** prematurely stuffed into a coffin, when one is still plain as day, on the whole, a breathing, thinking, perfectly living individual?"

Is the above grammatically correct, or does it need to be the wordier:

> "What is one to do, **after one has been** prematurely stuffed into a coffin -- when one is still plain as day, on the whole, a breathing, thinking, perfectly living individual?"

Comment: *after one has been prematurely stuffed into a coffin* is an adverb clause and *after being prematurely stuffed into a coffin* is a reduced adverb clause (a reduction of that full clause). They are both correct, but the reduced version sounds better.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and explanation!

Comment: @TinfoilHat You should make that an answer

Comment: It's basically a matter of personal choice.   In the above example the second option sounds awkward because "one" is repeated.

Comment: The first clause and the last clause have the snooty impersonal, so it should probly go in the middle too. Otherwise it looks like somebody's imitating Wodehouse badly.

Comment: If we read the first example without 'being' isn't still correct? What is one to do being prematurely stuffed into a coffin, when one is still plain as day, on the whole, a breathing, thinking, perfectly living individual?"